# Need hint to solve quant finance interview question.

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was asked this in an interview for a quant finance position: one box has $0$ USD or $100$ USD. It costs $20$ USD to play the game, I have $10$ USD and ask you for the extra $10$ USD . How many USD do you ask in return?

I believe the question is closely related to expected value/payoff, but has some trick around it?

What I understand is that there is probability $1/2$ that there is $0$ dollars in the box and probability $1/2$ that there is $100$ dollars. From this, I would say the expected value is $50$ dollars. Since the cost of the game is $20$ dollars and we split the cost, that would mean that we would split the gains as well. Hence, with prob $1/2$ we choose the $100$ USD box, from which I get $50$ USD, and with prob $1/2$ we choose the $0$ USD box, which means that my personal payoff is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 50 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 = 25$ USD. So I would ask him $25$ USD in return. It was some time ago, but I believe this was my answer, which I believe was wrong.

Does the above make sense, or did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: The question does not specify the probability of each case...you appear to be assuming that the cases are equally probable.  Other assumptions are possible.  Why not assume instead that the $\$20$ represented a fair price?  Seems much more likely.

Comment: Alternatively, you could ignore the unspecified probabilities and just offer half the payout.  That is clearly as fair as the original game.

Comment: You already asked this same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4433142/).  In the future, please do not delete and reask questions.  Rather, improve the question which you have already asked.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is a world without (statistical) arbitrage and transaction cost. I also assume that each game will end in an instant, so that interest rate or the time value of money can be neglected.

Since there is no arbitrage, the short answer is that I should ask for $10$ USD in return, otherwise I am bound to obtain a constant nonzero payoff and hence someone is able to exploit an arbitrage.

More specifically, from the the game master's point of view, if $p$ is the probability that a participant will win $100$ USD, we must have $100p=20$ (and hence $p=\frac15$, not $\frac12$), or else either the game master or the participant can exploit an arbitrage in the long run.

From your perspective, suppose that I ask for $k$ USD in return. Then your expected gain is $100p-10-k$, which is equal to $10-k$. Hence you need $k\le10$, or else you will not enter the game because you are expected to lose money.

From my perspective, I give you $10$ USD and receive $k$ USD in return. Therefore my net profit is $k-10$ and I want $k\ge10$.

Thus the only agreeable value of $k$ is $10$ USD.

Comment: This is good in the sense that it assumes the correct probability of the payoff but weird in the sense that it seems to assume the person who only has $10 will pay in either contingency.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Why is it weird? I am actually playing the role of a banker. My client wants to borrow from me some money to do some investment. I want him to repay his debt, regardless of whether his investment succeeds or not. In reality, I will ask for a collateral to secure the loan. In this question, if you don't believe that the borrower will pay when he loses the game, you cannot trust him to pay when he wins either.

Answer (score 0):

Initial investment is $20\$$ and the expected return is $50\$$.  So, the problem is equivalent to a fixed payoff of $50\$$, $100\%$ of the time.

So, the person who contributes $(1/2)$ the investment is entitled to $(1/2)$ of the expected payoff.

$(1/2)$ of $50\$$ is $25\$$.

This perfectly agrees with the Math in the OP's (original poster's) answer.  Therefore, I have no explanation for why this answer is deemed to be wrong.

---

**Edit**
An alternative answer just occurred to me, that is (arguably) more appropriate in the world of Finance, than it is in the world of abstract Math.

If this is a business venture, and you have a partner who is contributing $50\%$ of the investment, then your partner should get $50\%$ of the return, whatever the return is.  Thus, your partner should receive either $0\$$ or $50\$$, depending on whether the investment pays off.

Alternatively, if the $10\$$ that you receive from the other person is an **interest free loan**, rather than an investment, then the person should receive $10\$$ back as repayment on the loan, regardless of whether the investment paid off.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is \$79.99.

I am assuming that the negotiating process works as follows: you make an irrevocable, unchangeable offer for how much you want to accept, and the person with the initial \$10 either takes it or leaves it with no other opportunity to raise money or haggle with you.

The original person is willing to pay up to \$79.99 in the event that they win, since that is the greatest amount where they will still end up with a positive expected value (and money cannot be divided further than \$0.01). Therefore, this is how much you should ask for.

Comment: If you have the $20, why even cut them in for a (half) penny? Just shoo them out of the way and play yourself. If you are trying to exploit me, I reason that you must be a few bucks short as well.  Now that we both know we depend on the other’s consent to grab the free money here the only reasonable solution seems to be that we each take 15 ev.

Comment: (I know… you gave the assumptions explicitly, but couldn’t resist.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, depending on the assumptions you make about how to model the negotiation process, you might end up with a different answer. But we’re assuming that each side only has \$10, so I wouldn’t be able to do anything myself either.

Comment: Now that’s an assumption I don’t see in either the original text or the answer, but with that, I’ll show myself to the door

Answer (score 0):

The question is not stated well because it allows for multiple interpretations. First, we assume that both players are risk-neutral, i.e., they care about their expected gains. Second, player 1 pays back only in the case of winning the game. Finally, the probability of choosing each box is $1/2$.

---

The expected gain (the difference between the expected payoff and the value of non-participation) of players 1 and 2 are given by
\begin{align}
w_1&=0.5(100-x)-20, \\
w_2&=0.5x-20,
\end{align}
respectively. It is profitable for both players to charge any amount between $40\$$ and $60\$$. Since player 2 makes an offer, player 1 would be indifferent between paying $60\$$ back and non-participation.